# Concatenate the value of an variable with a string

Tags: python-3.x

I am using python3, i have a variable, That i want to use his value to define an other variable that concatenate the string character + the value of this variable as another variable:

Like this:
character + a = 'some value'

How can i do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic, but here is the answer:

```py
character = 'hello'
character = character + ' world'

print(character)
```

or alternatively, with two variables:

```py
character = 'hello'
a = ' world'
character = character + a
```

both of the above examples returns:

```
hello world
```